# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty signup page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following the Ruby on Rails tutorial, and I run into this error when I try to load the signup page:

**Showing C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/users/new.html.erb where line #6 raised:
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span6 offset3">
  <%= form_for (@user) do |f| %>     *this is the line 6 it's referring to*
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use `@user` in `form_for` under the `new` action, you'll need to initialize `@user` in the `new` method of the `UsersController`.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

end
```

An alternative would be to use `User.new` in the form itself, but that's generally not a best practice.  Logic like that belongs in the controller.